# Why tool tip is not displaying for page title in 'chrome'?

Tags: html

I have a html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>page title</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But the **tool tip** for title is not comming in chrome but it comes in mozilla.

if we increase the length of the page title then the tool tip  display in chrome
(eg:-`<title>page title title1 title2 title3 title4 title5</title>`)

can anyone say the reason for this?

Comment: Where do you expect a tooltip to come up?

Comment: Sounds like a major problem nonetheless! Will your customers cope without or is it a must?

Comment: Test page: http://jsbin.com/icani3

Comment: In Chrome if the content of the title exceeds the chrome tab then tool tip occurs because the size is long . if the content best first why there a necessary for a tool tip :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No browser I'm aware of displays a tooltip for the `<title></title>` tag. You're probably confusing it with the `title` **attribute**, e.g.:

```
<div title="Hello, world!">Box with title</div>
```

---

Please disregard my answer. I guess you are not talking about HTML. Some tabbed browsers, including Firefox and Chrome, display a tooltip when you put the mouse over a tab when the full title does not fit. If the title does fit, the tooltip is pointless. It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Chrome does when you hover over a tab, as does Firefox, IE 7, OK — *every* browser I tested.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome you will not see a tool tip when you hover over the *tab* if the text is short enough.
There isn't really anything you can do about that, tab tooltip isn't part of specifications, and any browser can behave in another way. (In fact, it seems even Chrome isn't consistent between operating systems)

Comment: That was my assumption — then I tested it, and it showed a tooltip for every tab, not matter what the length of the title.

Comment: @David - not for me, I tested too. I'm using 5.0.375.125 on XP.

Comment: Same version and platform that I tested on. How odd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have chrome to test but I'd wonder if it is only showing the tooltip when it is having to hide some of the page title in the tab name (assuming it is mousing over the tab that is generating the tooltip). This is mainly based on the fact that if its short it doesn't show the tooltip. There is no real spec that says what should be done with page titles though, except that they should be displayed. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE for the official spec (of HTML4) on what titles are for and how they might be rendered.

Comment: @Dustin Fineout: I have it at home, just not on my work computer. Perhaps I should get it on my work comp though... :)